# how do I changes a graph's theme based on a value?

Tags: razor, graph, charts, webmatrix

Using WebMatrix and razor (cshtml)

I have a chart, but the bars are default blue. I want to change their colour, based on their value ie a trigger value or target value.

How do I do this? I have a graph which uses the following code:

```
var db = Database.Open("data");
var itot = db.QueryValue("SELECT COALESCE(SUM(SUBTOTAL),0) from dbo.DR_TRANS where         TRANSDATE = datediff(d,0,getdate()) and transtype = 1 and SUBTOTAL >0") ?? 0;
var ctot = db.QueryValue("SELECT COALESCE(SUM(SUBTOTAL),0) from dbo.DR_TRANS where     TRANSDATE = datediff(d,0,getdate()) and TRANSTYPE = 1 and SUBTOTAL <0") ?? 0;
var itotnn = itot ?? 0;
var ctotnn = ctot ?? 0;
var nett = itotnn + ctotnn ?? 0;
var myChart = new Chart(width: 160, height: 500)
.AddTitle("Sales")
.AddSeries(
    name: "Today",
    xValue: new[] { "Actual", "Target" },
    yValues: new[] { nett, 18200 })
.Write();`
```